# What do we do instead of DFS on directed graphs?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal

All the example of DFS I've seen so far are for undirected graph.
In a directed graph the basic DFS algorithm won't work because some vertex will be unreachable.

The algorithm I'm talking about :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

```
1  procedure DFS-iterative(G,v):
2      let S be a stack
3      S.push(v)
4      while S is not empty
5          v = S.pop()
6          if v is not labeled as discovered:
7              label v as discovered
8              for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do 
9                  S.push(w)
```

Example :

### [image]

So let's say I start with '1' I will never access 4,5,6 with this algorithm.

For directed graph it looks like we have to know all the vertex and iterate through them.

And so we cannot use a DFS for directed graph ?

Is there a DFS variant or another algorithm ?

Comment: DFS can be used on directed graphs just as well as on undirected graphs. Given a vertex, in both cases it finds all vertices reachable from it. If you want to explore the entire graph, you should loop over all starting vertices, skipping those which you've already reached.

Comment: Python-specific questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is not specific to DFS.

When looking at directed graphs, even for connected graphs not all nodes are reachable from everywhere. That's why the notion of a graph being [*strongly* connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) exists.

In a strongly connected graph, graph traversals starting in a single node will reach all nodes.
In other graphs, it won't.

This affects all traversal algorithms. For some reason, (some) canonical BFS implementations include looping over all starting nodes but DFS implementations do not. I don't know why; I assume historical reasons. There certainly is no conceptual difference; you can just as easily restart DFS with new starting nodes until you cover the whole graph.

Answer (score 4):

DFS suffers from the same problem in undirected graphs: if your graph is not connected, then starting DFS with an initial vertex $v$ will only explore the connected component of $v$. In a similar fashion, if the graph is directed, then DFS will only explore the vertices reachable from $v$.

The solution is the same in both cases: loop over all vertices, and start DFS with each of the vertices functioning as the initial vertex. If you skip vertices which you have already discovered, then the resulting algorithm will still run in linear time.